# Baking and Tahini Halva: replacing sugar/honey with corn syrup (pure dextrose)?

Tags: sugar, honey, corn, glucose-syrup

I just read a recipe for DIY Tahini Halva made using honey and another recipe (sugar free) of Tahini halva made with erythritol.

However, Erythritol is not cheap and I don't mind carbs like "dextrose", so I'm considering other options.

I am avoiding the use of fructose.

I've considered replacing the honey with corn syrup, but I don't know the ratio. I've also considered a Dextrose powder + water mixture as a substitute.

However, I'm not sure if the physics and chemistry perfectly work out in either case, since sugar can be tricky.

What fructose-free sugars could I use as a replacement in a Halva recipe, and with what ratio?

Comment: One of the tricks of substituting sugar in halva is that a huge part of halva's texture comes from the specific way sugar crystals form. Almost anything you use to replace it that doesn't crystallize the same way will potentially be an issue. Honey is often high in fructose as well, but I don't know which sugar is responsible for halva's unique texture.

Comment: The nutrition angle of this question is out of scope for this stack exchange. "Can I make halva out of glucose syrup?" is an on-topic culinary question. But we should avoid making health claims.